# ASP.NET Drop Down List custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm adding a custom attribute to drop down list like this,

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFirst" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In code behind I'm adding custom attribute,

```
ListItem deleteMeLi = new ListItem("Mango", "");
deleteMeLi.Attributes.Add("data-IsMangoRotten", "0");
ddlFirst.Items.Add(deleteMeLi);
```

Now when I try to get value back like this,

```
 int rottenM = Convert.ToInt32(ddlFirst.SelectedItem.Attributes["data-IsMangoRotten"].ToString());
```

It throws object is null expection,

While debugging I figured out that the count of Attributes of ddlFirst are 0, however in HTML I can see the attrbutes using developer tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `DropDownList`s are rendered as `<select>` elements on the client side, and as such, you cannot add an attribute to an `<option>` element in HTML and retrieve it on the server-side because they are NOT posted. Sure, you can access them on the client-side via plain Javascript but don't expect them to be posted to the server.

Comment: @CustomizedName I can think of several alternatives: 1. Don't use a `DrowpDownList` and instead write a custom server control that supports this functionality -easy to implement but will take some time- 2. Simply get the attribute value on the client side, stick it to an `input type="hidden"` element and then read the value of this `input type="hidden"` element on the server-side. It's a bit of a hack but is quick to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine on its own.

I suspect you're trying to get the SelectedItem's attributes before you've added deleteMeLi to ddlFirst, so then you try to get the attributes of a null object and get the exception.

Check when in the Page life cycle you're adding the ListItem and when you're trying to get the attribute value.

Comment: -1. This is incorrect. custom attributes to option elements are not posted to the server.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the case.. as I am getting text and value + i am addin while loading and a click event trying ot get the values

Comment: @Icarus, they wouldn't be if the OP was adding them in markup, but they're added server-side. I tested it myself and it works fine.

Comment: @spongessuck yes, as I said, they are added correctly but they are not posted. There's no way you can read them back.

Comment: @Icarus I see what you mean- at next postback they would be lost.